# Python "sklearn" ValueError

Tags: python, scikit-learn

hope you are having a great day! I know the problem is silly and most of you can probably figure it out. But i do need help. So yeah. Here's the problem:

The code goes something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
X = data.drop(columns = "Answers")
Y = data["Answers"]

algorithm = DecisionTreeClassifier()

algorithm.fit(X, Y)
```

And I know I'm dumb and probably don't know why its outputting this shi*:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-0deefc30b34f> in <module>
      9 algorithm = DecisionTreeClassifier()
     10 
---> 11 algorithm.fit(X, Y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    888         """
    889 
--> 890         super().fit(
    891             X, y,
    892             sample_weight=sample_weight,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    154             check_X_params = dict(dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    155             check_y_params = dict(ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
--> 156             X, y = self._validate_data(X, y,
    157                                        validate_separately=(check_X_params,
    158                                                             check_y_params))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    427                 # :(
    428                 check_X_params, check_y_params = validate_separately
--> 429                 X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)
    430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    431             else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    596                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    597                 else:
--> 598                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    599             except ComplexWarning:
    600                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1779 
   1780     def __array__(self, dtype=None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1781         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1782 
   1783     def __array_wrap__(self, result, context=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: "Wat's your name?"
```

Thank you for viewing this problem and perhaps in solving it. Have a great day!

Comment: sklearn algorithms cannot convert text data directly to features, you have to either convert them to vectors, or drop that column.

Comment: See their [working with text data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) tutorial